# Edit a default value in SQL if column exists

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

I have a database that is undergoing a refactoring now.
In that refactoring, I moved a column from one table to another.
In the following query, I create a new row in the table with 5 attributes.
I need to change this query so that ***if*** the table `static.connected_shelf` contains the attribute `iot_device_type_fk`,  its value will be 2, and if that attribute is not in the table, nothing will happen.

```
        cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO static.connected_shelf(name, is_active, local_tz_offset, store_fk, template_fk)
        SELECT %(shelf_name)s, %(is_active)s, %(local_tz_offset)s, S.pk, T.pk
        FROM static.stores S, static.template T 
        WHERE S.name=%(store_name)s 
        AND T.name=%(template_name)s 
        """, {'shelf_name': shelf_name, 'is_active': is_active, 'store_name': store_name,
              'template_name': template_name,
              'iot_device_type_name': iot_device_type_name, 'local_tz_offset': local_tz_offset})
```

Comment: The only way to do that is check for the table columns first and then have two different queries for each case

Comment: You would have to write something like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS(<corelated subquery)`  where the corelated subquery is a query where you check the information_schema.COLUMNS.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The problem isnt the rows. The problem is the missing column

Comment: *"The problem isnt the rows. The problem is the missing column "* indeed @JuanCarlosOropeza ive updated mine comment just before your comment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Still OP want insert a default value if the column exists and nothing if doesnt. So  he need 2 different queries and a `IF` statement

Comment: well @JuanCarlosOropeza i think the topicstarter could read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.

Comment: *"Still OP want insert a default value if the column exists and nothing if doesnt. So he need 2 different queries and a IF statement –"* @JuanCarlosOropeza you could use UNION, ORDER BY and a LIMIT to extend mine example more or less like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLCFAdk3F3fzVPdV1MjcD4/0) .. But it's is hard if not impossible to suggest something **solid** if the topicstarter does not provide example data and expected results.